# turbo prolog on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, turbo-prolog, visual-prolog

i am a complete noob to Prolog. I wish to install `turbo prolog` in ubuntu. How do i do that. I googled it but all in vain. Is there any other option to `turbo prolog` for ubuntu?

Comment: should be *visual* Prolog now

Comment: if you go for visual Prolog, you will need to use Wine (Windows emulator)

Answer (score 1):

You should search for visual prolog: http://www.visual-prolog.com/

That said, I use [swi-prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) with emacs and I find it very good. If you are already familiar with emacs, you should consider it. There's a nice and detailed guide on [use swi with emacs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/GnuEmacs.html) on the swi-prolog page.

Comment: language is different, turbo prolog has many specific constructs ad hoc.

Comment: He asked for other options, I understood it as "other implementations of the prolog language". Also, he tagged his question with the swi-prolog TAG..

Comment: You're right, maybe z22 has a specific need for turbo prolog, maybe some old program to run. In case, should be worth to 'port' to SWI-Prolog...

Comment: can i do the same work with swi-prolog as with turbo-prolog? As i said i am very much new to prolog so i wish to learn it from scratch and wish to install it in ubuntu.

Comment: If you are new to prolog and you are free to choose any implementation, I suggest swi-prolog. It is robust, it has a big library, it is well documented, easy to use and goes very well with Ubuntu. See here:

http://www.fraber.de/university/prolog/comparison.html

on the top of the page, the "What Prolog do I Need?"

Comment: thanks mate! i installed swi-prolog from ubuntu software center but unable to locate it. In the command prompt i typed swipl and the prolog prompt appeared. i am trying to implement the program given in the following link- http://www.scribd.com/doc/7348208/Prolog-Program-1, but in vain. When i type'.', the program terminates. and error appears in the terminal. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

You have here step by step installation for turboprolog under ubuntu.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1653742

But i recommend that you use SWI-prolog or XSB prolog, because as you can see turbo prolog only works in DOS so you need DOSBox emulator...all that is to complicated. Just use SWI-prolog or XSB prolog-much easier installation.